# LinearLayout how to make TextView wrap content with limit?

Tags: android

I want to show 2 TextView in one horizontal LinearLayout, the first TextView is variable and its length may change. The second is always (B). So I want something like this:

|AAA(B)--------|

When A is very long, it should show ellipse in middle:

|AAAA...AAAA(B)|

To solve the problem, I tried wrap content for A:

```
<LinearLayout orientation="Horizontal" width="match_parent">
    <TextView id="@+id/A" width="wrap_content" />
    <TextView id="@+id/B" width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But there is problem when A is very long, B disappears. It becomes

|AAAAAAAAAAA|

I also tried to add layout_weight:

```
<LinearLayout orientation="Horizontal" width="match_parent">
    <TextView id="@+id/A" width="wrap_content" layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView id="@+id/B" width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But there is problem when A is very short, there are unwanted space between A and B, It becomes

|AAA-----(B)|  ("-" for space)

I don't want space here.

Is there any way to make wrap_content with a max limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a Horizontal LinearLayout you can achieve this using `android:layout_weight="1"` to the variable TextView A and  `android:layout_weight="0"` to the fixed TextView B. Also the LinearLayout must have `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

Xml structure is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:text="B"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Result when A is Short:**

[image: shortTextViewA]

**Result when A is Long:**

[image: longTextViewA]

Comment: Yes making the LinearLayout itself variable in length seems to be an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a constraint layout to achieve this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".presentation.list.CampaignListActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/B"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/B"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:ellipsize="middle"
       android:text="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/A"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When A is short, both will take half space and it becomes
|A-----(B)-----|

Answer (score 0):

Here You Go !

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_A"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="this is a long text field kdsalfj lksadjlfja sdljfljas dlfjlas djflk js dalk and this text is more than 20fj"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_B"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_B"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Less Text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_A"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And then add below code in your OnCreate method:

```
if (tvA.text.length > 50) {
   tvA.text = "${tvA.text.take(20)}...${tvA.text.takeLast(20)}"
}
```

You have to add the above code lines somewhere so they get executed as the Activity is lauched (e.g. in OnCreate() Function of the Activity)

Comment: "${tvA.text.take(20)}...${tvA.text.takeLast(20)}" how do we make sure 46 characters will be displayed?

Comment: divide 46 in half, then add 23 in take(23) and 23 in takeLast(23). likewise if you want 46 chars including the dots then place something less than 23.